# why are there two outputs for the same c prog below?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n;
    n+=2;
    printf("sum=%d", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Here the `'Sum'=2`

Another program:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n,a=2;
    n+=a;
    printf("sum=%d", n);
    return 0;
 }
```

here the output `'sum' = 3`
 WHY so?? What is the problem in the code??

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: the `main()` function only has two valid signatures.  Both those signatures have a return type of `int`

Comment: the posted code contains undefined behavior, where the uninitialized variable 'n' has a value added to it.  Since 'n' is not initialized, it will contain what ever trash happens to be in the stack/memory at that location.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Undefined Behavior. Using uninitialized variables (`n` in both snippets) can produce unexpected results, meaning that running the first code twice might produce different outputs. There is no "correct" output for either of the codes, but if you'll set `n` to a specific value in both codes, you'll start getting consistent results.

This is UB (Undefined Behavior):

```
main()
{
int n;
printf("sum=%d", n);
return 0;
}
```

This is not:

```
main()
{
int n = 0;
printf("sum=%d", n);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you don't assign a value to a local variable in C, its value is undefined. So in some cases it will be `0`, in some `1`, in some, something else entirely. You cannot know what it will be and you should never rely on it. Instead, initialize your local variables:

```
int n = 0; // initialization
n += 2;
printf("sum=%d", n); // will always print 2
```